# How to download a dat file from a weblink into a path in SDcard in my Android app?

Tags: java, android, http, android-intent

In the app im developing i'l have to download a dat file along with a xml file from a webserver link.
There was no problem in downloading the xml but while downloading dat file it is throwing exception.How can i over come this state.Thank you guys..

Exception

```
    02-01 16:33:34.713: W/System.err(1404): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.myingage.com/bkpdrctry/dontwo.dat
    02-01 16:33:34.723: W/System.err(1404):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1162)
```

The actual code is below

```
    protected static void downloadFile(String stringUrl, String path){
        try {
           URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
           DebugLog.LOGD("URL " +url );

           //create the new connection
           HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

          //set up some things on the connection
          urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
          urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

          //and connect!
          urlConnection.connect();

          File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
          //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename
          //which we want to save the file as.
          File file = new File(SDCardRoot,path);
          DebugLog.LOGD("download to sd card " +url );  

          //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
          FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
          DebugLog.LOGD("File written successfully in " +path );

          //this will be used in reading the data from the internet
          InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

          //this is the total size of the file
          int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
          //variable to store total downloaded bytes
          int downloadedSize = 0;

          //create a buffer...
          byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
          int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

          //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
          while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
               //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
               fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
               //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
               downloadedSize += bufferLength;
               //this is where you would do something to report the prgress, like this maybe
               //updateProgress(downloadedSize, totalSize);

          }
          //close the output stream when done
          fileOutput.close();
     //catch some possible errors...
     } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
```

The above function is called here:

```
    downloadFile("http://www.myingage.com/bkpdrctry/dontwo.xml","/Test/dontwo.xml");
    downloadFile("http://www.myingage.com/bkpdrctry/dontwo.dat","/Test/dontwo.dat");
```

Comment: You haven't dat file on your web server ;)

Comment: hey Dawid.I have the .dat file in the webserver. If you try opening the file in the web browser , obviously it ll not open :) cos the file is a compressed file tht is not supported by the browser. The android app is capable of recognising the .dat file. Could you suggest how i could download a dat file into my android app

Answer (score 2):

Open `http://www.myingage.com/bkpdrctry/dontwo.dat` on your browser.

Throws `HTTP 404`.

Comment: Marcelo: First il Thank you for your reply.The dontwo.dat is a compressed file which gets recognised by the android app.You couldnt open the dat file in the browser because the browser could nt recognise .dat files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.The dontwo.dat is a compressed file which gets recognised by the android app.You wont be able to open the dat file in the browser because the browser could nt recognise .dat files. I would like to know how i could download the .dat file into my android app from a web server. i also checked in the web host manager of the website and the file exists.

Comment: hey guys , found out what went wrong. The godaddy server ,which is the hosting server for the website site doesnt recognise the dat file.i renamed the .dat file as dontwo.dat.jpg and it worked . i could download. :) Thank you guys for your contribution